# How can I tell whether a numpy boolean array contains only a single block of `True`s?

Tags: python, numpy

If I have a numpy array containing booleans, say the output of some math comparison, what's the best way of determining whether that array contains only a single contiguous block of `True`s, e.g.

```
array([False, False, False, True, True, True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

i.e. where the sequence `...,True, False, ..., True...` never occurs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`numpy.diff`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) is useful in this case. You can count the number of -1's in the `diff`ed array.

Note, you'd also need to check the last element -- if it's True, there wouldn't be a -1 in the `diff`ed array to indicate that.  Better yet, you can append `False` to the array before `diff`ing.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([False, False, False, True, True, True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
d = np.diff(np.asarray(a, dtype=int))
d
=> array([ 0,  0,  1,  0,  0, -1,  0,  0])
(d < 0).sum()
=> 1
```

To append `False` at the end:

```
b = np.append(a, [ False ])
d = np.diff(np.asarray(b, dtype=int))
...
```

Now, "the sequence ...,True, False, ..., True... never occurs" iff `(d<0).sum() < 2`.

A trick to avoid the `append` operation (and make your code more obscure) is by doing: `(d<0).sum() + a[-1] < 2` (i.e., if a[-1] is True, count it as a block).  This would only work if a is not empty, of course.

Comment: `[True, True, True, False]` and `[True, True, False, False, True, True]` would produce unexpected results.

Comment: It seems you would need to add `False` to both ends.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, as I understand the question, we want to return True if "the sequence ...,True, False, ..., True... never occurs", and False if it occurs.  The condition `(d<0).sum() < 2` gives the right result in both of your examples. I edited my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

Not a `numpy` native approach, but you can use `itertools.groupby` to reduce blocks of continuous values into a single item, and then check that only a truthy value appears once using `any`. Since `grouped` is an iterable the first `any` returns `True` as soon as a truthy value is found, you then resume the check on the remainder of the iterable and make sure there is not another truthy value.

```
from itertools import groupby

def has_single_true_block(sequence):
    grouped = (k for k, g in groupby(sequence))
    has_true = any(grouped)
    has_another_true = any(grouped)
    return has_true and not has_another_true
```

Comment: This is a nice answer, do you know if the sort circuiting behavior of any is guaranteed in general?

Comment: @BiRico yes... `any` will return `True` as soon as any truthy value is found... The code it's equivalent to is at: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any

Answer (score 1):

If you only have a single block of Trues, that means you either have one transition in the array or you have two transitions and the array starts and ends with False. Also there is the trivial case where the whole array is True. So you could do something like:

```
def singleBlockTrue(array):
   if len(array) == 0:
       return False
   transitions = (array[1:] != array[:-1]).sum()
   if transitions == 0:
       return array[0]
   if transitions == 1:
       return True
   if transitions == 2:
       return not array[0]
   return False
```

This is effectively the same logic, but the code is a little cleaner.

```
def singleBlockTrue(array):
    if len(array) == 0:
        return False
    transitions = (array[1:] != array[:-1]).sum()
    transitions = transitions + array[0] + array[-1]
    return transitions == 2
```

Some timeings related to the comments:

```
In [41]: a = np.zeros(1000000, dtype=bool)

In [42]: timeit a[:-1] != a[1:]
100 loops, best of 3: 2.93 ms per loop

In [43]: timeit np.diff(a.view('uint8'))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.45 ms per loop

In [44]: timeit np.diff(a.astype('uint8'))
100 loops, best of 3: 3.41 ms per loop

In [45]: timeit np.diff(np.array(a, 'uint8'))
100 loops, best of 3: 3.42 ms per loop
```

Comment: I like your first function. This implementation can run very fast, taking advantage of the fast operations on bool-arrays. However, if you used `numpy.diff` and avoid the slicing+comparison, it would be even faster.

Comment: @shx2, I'd really be surprised if diff was faster than != because you need to copy a bool array to do a diff. (Copy is O(N) operation where slice is O(1) operation). Then you need to do another < or != operation on the diff result.

Comment: both options create a new array as a result. My guess is that `numpy.diff` uses a single pointer to traverse the input array, whereas `!=` must use two. I'd be surprised if `(array[1:] != array[:-1])` is faster than `numpy.diff`..

Comment: Well, you were right. I checked, and `(array[1:] != array[:-1])` is indeed faster. Must be due to the fast bool-array comparison (memcmp).

Comment: So diff can be faster in some situations, as shown above, but that doesn't include the second pass you'd need to do. The final code would look something like `np.diff(a.view('uint8')) != 0`, which to me is pretty ugly.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

def has_single_true_block(arr):
    if not len(arr):
        return False
    blocks = len(np.array_split(arr, np.where(np.diff(arr) != 0)[0] + 1))
    if blocks > 3:
        return False
    elif blocks == 3 and arr[0] and arr[-1]:
        return False
    elif blocks == 1 and not arr[0]:  # 0 True blocks
        return False
    return True

# TESTS

a1 = np.array([False, False, True, True, True, False, False], dtype=bool)
has_single_true_block(a1)  # => True

a2 = np.array([True, True, False, False], dtype=bool)
has_single_true_block(a2)  # => True

a3 = np.array([False, False, True, True], dtype=bool)
has_single_true_block(a3)  # => True

f1 = np.array([False, False, True, False, True, False, False], dtype=bool)
has_single_true_block(f1)  # => False

f2 = np.array([True, True, False, False, True, True], dtype=bool)
has_single_true_block(f2)  # => False

f3 = np.array([False, False, False], dtype=bool)
has_single_true_block(f3)  # => False
```

Comment: Naive answer, not very fast/efficient, but leaving up for illustration of the effectiveness of other answers.